# Correctly filtering NSImage/CIImage using CIFilter and CISpotColor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, image-processing, cifilter

**Please note:** This is for a Cocoa command line app running on Mac OSX, and **NOT an iOS app**

I am having some trouble trying to understand the [Limited Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISpotColor) supplied by Apple for the **CISpotColor** filter (using **CIFilter** ).

---

### TL DR;

1) Is there more documentation I am missing somewhere about CIFilter, specifically CISpotColor?

2) Given what I am trying to achieve (described below pictorially, but briefly: replace everything that does not "look red" with white, and force every thing that "looks red(ish)" to either solid red, or simply black), is CISpotColor the correct filter I should be using?

3) If not, what filter(s) do you suggest (or should I try and code a custom one?)

4) If CISSpotColor is the correct filter, what parameters should I use to achieve what I am trying to achieve. If I need to use several passes of the CISpotColor CIFilter, that's fine, I don't expect you to code it for me, just point me in the right direction.

---

### More detail and background to the above questions:

The [link above](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISpotColor) gives a list of parameters, some default values, and an example before and after picture, but no sample code that generated the sample after image, and no explanation of what the parameters actually mean, or what their valid ranges are.

To be honest, I am not entirely sure if CISpotColor is the filter I am after, as other than it's name, and the sentence "**Replaces one or more color ranges with spot colors**", there is no explanation of how it does what it does.

Since it's the filter that seems to describe what I am after, I chose it as a starting point to get my head around working with filters in this manner.

**Input picture (a frame from a video)**
[image]

**Desired output (option 1 - solid red - created using GIMP)**
[image]

**Desired output (option 2 - solid black  - also created using GIMP)**
[image]

**What I am getting with my code (see below for listing)**
[image]

This is close to what I need, but it does not appear to take into account the fact that areas that are grey or "whiteish" in the original image will have similar amounts of red,green and blue, rather as opposed to predominantly red, which would make it "look red". I could work with it if it filtered out the area you see in the bottom right hand corner, which is clearly just being included because there are some red pixels there (as well as some green and blue, making it generally grey in the original).

**Here is the complete "main.m" for the cocoa command line app (Mac OSX)**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>



@interface NSImage(saveAsJpegWithName)
- (void) saveAsPNGWithName:(NSString*) fileName;
- (NSImage*) filterEverythingButRed ;
@end

@implementation NSImage(saveAsJpegWithName)

- (void) saveAsPNGWithName:(NSString*) fileName
{
    NSData *imageData = [self TIFFRepresentation];
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
    NSDictionary *imageProps = nil;
    imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:imageProps];
    [imageData writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
}

-(NSImage*) filterEverythingButRed {

    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:[self TIFFRepresentation]];

    CIFilter *hf = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISpotColor"];
    [hf setDefaults];
    [hf setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [hf setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
    [hf setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
    [hf setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1] forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
    [hf setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [hf valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

    NSImage *resultImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[outputImage extent].size];
    NSCIImageRep *rep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:outputImage];
    [resultImage addRepresentation:rep];

    return resultImage;
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (argc == 1) {

        NSString * appname = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s", argv[0]];

        NSLog(@"Usage: %@ filename", appname);

    }  else {

        NSString * filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s", argv[1]];

        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:filename]) {

            NSLog(@"opening file:%@", filename);


            NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];

            [[img filterEverythingButRed]
             saveAsPNGWithName:[[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingString:@"-red.png"]];




        } else {

            NSLog(@"file not found:%@", filename);
        }

    }


    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i've found a workaround that seems to work, but it's unclear as to why - if you set define the same settings for all inputCenterColor1, inputCenterColor2 & inputCenterColor1 (using color=[1.0,0.0,0.0],closeness = 0.5 and contrast=1.0), it works. not sure why you need to do all 3, if you have any insights, would be helpful. it also lets you do the same for green and blue, and it seems to correctly filter as desired(for my case use). i'll leave this question open for other searchers/posters.

Answer (score 3):

`CISpotColor` essentially does four color operations:

1. replace all colors close to `inputCenterColor1` with `inputReplacementColor1`.
2. replace all colors close to `inputCenterColor2` with `inputReplacementColor2`.
3. replace all colors close to `inputCenterColor3` with `inputReplacementColor3`.
4. replace everything else with white.

By default, the input colors are set to various reddish/pinkish shades. You can find these by examining those filter values in code after you construct it and call `setDefaults` -- but for ease of illustration, here's all the default values in a screenshot from the [Core Image Fun House](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUuk5.png) sample code app:

[image: CISpotColor defaults]

Applying the filter with default options gets you this:

[image: filtered with defaults]

Notice that the red ring (the part you're trying to have be the only remaining element in the image) looks like the default `inputReplacementColor3`, and the lit areas in the lower right look like the default `inputReplacementColor2`... just like they do in [your output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMgvJ.png). That's because you've only configured the first pair of center/replacement colors, and you've left the other two at their reddish/pinkish defaults.

If you want to disable the second and third color replacements, turn their *Closeness* parameter down to 0.0 and/or their *Contrast* parameter up to 1.0. To be safe, you might also set their *Center Color* to something that doesn't appear in your image. In your test image, I find that just turning down *Closeness* is enough:

[image: new settings]

This gets the following output:

[image: new output]

By the way, spot color replacement like this is sort of a simple form of a Color LookUp Table (CLUT) operation, which is implemented by the [`CIColorCube`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorCube) filter. If you want to be able to fine-tune color replacement beyond what `CISpotColor` provides, the color cube option might be a good bet. There's a tutorial on using it for a green-screen effect [in Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW2).

#### TLDR:

1. Set appropriate values for *all* the filter parameters, not just the first few, or other default values might do things you aren't expecting. Setting `inputCloseness2` and `inputCloseness3` to zero and leaving everything else default (but for the `input...1` parameters you've already set) seems to work for your test image.
2. Having a live test environment for your filters really helps you fine tune parameters (and make sure the defaults are what you expect). [Core Image Fun House](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUuk5.png) is great for that.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct,  there still is no documentation.  for instance using just "core image fun house" as your source of info would not give you an indication that it is extremely important which color you put in input spot 1,  and which color into input spot 2...  switching them gives you a profoundly different result,  and i've found many more gotchas in this particular filter.   Like the "max" values on some of the parameters,  the code is more what you'd call.... "guidelines" than actual rules. :)  using "fun house" as a source,  will get you down a rabbit hole that has about 10 exits,  with no signs telling you where those exits are.

here are some notes I kept by throwing in crazy numbers into this filter and seeing what "stuck" against the wall.  (needs more if someone so chooses)

```
            //-------------------------  picked up a red ski helmet in full sun,  included all shadows on helmet, and some yellow from sun..  near perfect mask,  but also picked up most skin tones.
        //--------------------------  used a color from the helmet color: 0.662745 0.188235 0.223529 1.0  then stretched values to normalize to have one color 1.0 --------------
        CIFilter *clampFilter1 = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISpotColor"];


        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.09 blue:0.33] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.86) forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.00) forKey: @"inputCloseness2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast2"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:1.0 blue:0.56] forKey: @"inputCenterColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputCloseness3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast3"];


        //---------------------------- picked up a blue jacket total, including all the shadows, a near perfect mask of a fairly blue jacket all ranges  ---------------------------
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.01 green:0.165 blue:1.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.86) forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.0) forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

        //---------------------------- did not need this input but experimenting and left it in to add other changes,  same with below experiments  ---------------------------
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.01 green:0.165 blue:1.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.86) forKey: @"inputCloseness2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.0) forKey: @"inputContrast2"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0.5] forKey: @"inputCenterColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.99) forKey: @"inputCloseness3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.99) forKey: @"inputContrast3"];



        //---------------------------- picked up all reds,  total,  including some purples,  also picked up all skin tones  -----------------------------------------------------------
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast2"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast3"];


        //---------------------------- removed all reds,  total,  turned all blues all ranges.. to green  -----------------------------------------------------------
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast2"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast3"];


        //---------------------------- removed most reds,   but skin still some tint,  turned all blues all ranges to green  -----------------------------------------------------------
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.80) forKey: @"inputContrast2"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.99) forKey: @"inputContrast3"];


        //---------------------------- picked up  shadow blue/purple replaced with green  -----------------------------------------------------------
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness1"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(1.00) forKey: @"inputContrast1"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness2"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.80) forKey: @"inputContrast2"];

        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0] forKey: @"inputCenterColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] forKey: @"inputReplacementColor3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.90) forKey: @"inputCloseness3"];
        [clampFilter1 setValue:@(0.99) forKey: @"inputContrast3"];
```